# Assigning listbox item to picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, listbox, picturebox

I created a button that brings a dialog asking for a picture:

```
        OpenFileDialog s = new OpenFileDialog();
        s.Title = "Open image";
        s.Filter = "Image Files (*.bmp;*.jpg;*.jpeg,*.png)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.JPEG;*.PNG";
        if (s.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
}
```

I want to assign each added image to the listbox item that the user selected. How is it possible? Also I have a button that exports the listbox:

```
        SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
        save.Title = "Save the listbox";
        save.FileName = "list.txt";
        save.Filter = "Text File | *.txt";
        if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(save.OpenFile());
            for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
            }
            writer.Dispose();
            writer.Close();
```

This is what I have so far. How can it export the picture assigned to the listbox too?

Thanks.

Comment: _How can it export the picture assigned to the listbox too?_  ...Export the picture(s) to what exactly?

Comment: Anything in a ListBox needs to provide a useful ToString method. Image doesn't. Create a Class the contains an Image (or Bitmap) and a name-string, maybe like this: `class NamedImage
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Image Image { get; set; }

        public NamedImage(string name, Image img)
        {
            Name = name; Image = img;
        }

        public override string  ToString()
        {
           return Name;
        }
    }`

Comment: I want to export them with the list (the second part of the code). And I want every image to have the name of the listbox item. Is this even possible?

Comment: Items are objects and have by default no name. You need to store what you call 'name' when you import the images.